# How do I properly sort through dynamically created storage using a function such as calloc/malloc so it behaves in a FIFO manner?

Tags: c++, calloc

I am very new to programming and self-taught so forgive me if I use some incorrect terminology.

I am using calloc() to create storage space in my heap which I can guarantee to be initialized as there are no junk values put into. From observing the behavior of calloc it seems the there is one singular pointer used to point to the entire block of addresses of specified size type. Once I increment to store something in the next address, there is no longer anything pointing to the previous address. I searched for answers here and could not code anything that worked. Eventually I just made a counter to keep track of how many times I incremented the pointer, then decremented by that amount and then to read from my dynamically created array I again incremented through it.

While it did work, I can't help but think there is a better way of doing this. I also think I am far along enough to where I can get by using poor methodology, yet not knowledgeable enough to even know what terms to use when trying to research my issue. I understand the calloc array is stored on the heap until I free each contiguous space allocated for it. I began to search for "Heap sorting" but I believe this is beyond my scope and overly complicated for what I am attempting to do. I have also stored it in a predefined array working as a buffer but again I would like to only read from the calloc array directly, even if that involves using another pointer to do so. To avoid further rambling, if someone could be so kind to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Being very new to programming, it is not a good learning stage to deal with pointer and manual memory allocation.

Comment: Well, I am 5 months in. Did I not articulate my problem well enough for you to understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

For now just forget about the C level functions like `malloc` and `free`.

Also forget about C++ level ditto operators like `new` and `delete`.

Use [`std::queue` from the `<queue>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

---

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    queue<int> q;
    q.push( 7 );
    for( int i = 1; i <= 29; ++i )
    {
        const int x = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if( x % 7 == 0 )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < 10; ++j )
            {
                q.push( 10*x + j );
            }
        }
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold onto a variable that keeps track of the original pointer returned by calloc.

Also, you can access different values in calloc by treating it as an array.

If you post some code, I can give you an example.